# how to publish the GitHub app to remote users of Windows Server 2012?

Tags: remote-desktop, git, windows-server-2012, github, remoteapp

I think I have an idea what publishing apps to users mean on a Windows Server I administer.
(More on that in [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10817.publishing-remoteapps-in-windows-server-2012.aspx) wiki, perhaps)

However, it seems to work well with apps with exe's in the main Program Files folders, or wherever I can find them outside my personal folders (i.e. folders belonging to a user account, even if an admin one).

I tried to download the GitHub app from windows.github.com, but it hides its exe. I could not reverse engineer the special shortcut the installer created, and among the exes I found, only installers could be pushed to users, which of course did not help them.

Hopefully it is a common problem: How can I easily set up our users on GitHub, then?

Please see my related [question](https://superuser.com/q/704230/173181) about how to relax restrictions on the accounts to install and use GitHub.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the properties for the shorcut to the application.  I suspect I know what is going on.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thanks, and sorry I cannot post a screenshot. But I have learned that GitHub «uses Microsoft's ClickOnce installer, which can only be installed on a per-user basis to the %LocalAppData% directory.» But my users cannot install anything, catch 22.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I thought was the case.  This is the best advice I can provide.  There isn't an offline installer.  So unless you want to make an exception for this installer you will have to select another cient.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks, I am happy to accept or upvote your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is no offline installer. GitHub uses Microsoft's ClickOnce installer, which can only be installed on a per-user basis to the %LocalAppData% directory. So unless you want to make an exception for this installer, you will need to choose another cient.

credit goes to @Ramhound in the comments!

Comment: @-notification only works in comments, not in answers.

Comment: Or not even in comments, see the thread under the question. [off/meta]