# what ports to open up for GitHub to install and work?

Tags: networking, git, firewall, windows-server-2012, github

I want to use GitHub on a server where user accounts are not supposed to be able to go online otherwise. The GitHub Windows app does not even install without users' downloading it themselves (see my previous [question](https://superuser.com/q/703228/173181)), but also for my regular use, what is the bare minimum one needs to open up?

By opening up I mean user account privileges (under Windows Server 2012 specifically) or firewall rules.

See also [the follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21233339/938408) on StackOverflow about whether an open port 9418 is all I need.

Thanks!

Comment: [check this thread out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88476/trying-to-load-files-from-github-through-a-firewall-is-impossibly-slow-any-sugg)

Comment: @Raystafarian Excellent, thanks a lot. Does it mean that port 9418 open would result in a fully functional GitHub client?

Comment: From what I gather 9418 is for git:\\ and if that's unavailable, 443

Comment: @Raystafarian And you think the GitHub client (a Windows app) uses this, then. Hope you are right, thanks. We got into some confusion in comments over at SE about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21233339/938408

Answer (score 1):

An official GitHub help [page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist) might have the answer:

> Current IP Addresses
>
> We currently serve our applications via the following IP address
>   range. Note: This is in CIDR notation.
>
> 192.30.252.0/22
>
> In order to access all of our services, please ensure that TCP ports 22, 80, 443, and 9418 are allowed via the IP range
>   above.
>
> These IPs may change (or be added to) in the future, and we will keep
>   this page up to date.
>
> Service Hook IP Addresses
>
> We highly recommend that you don't white list IPs for Service Hooks.
>   Instead, setup HTTPS and basic authentication to verify incoming
>   requests.
>
> Sample IPs from RequestBin
>
> Hooks will come from the following IP address range. Note: This is in
>   CIDR notation.
>
> 192.30.252.0/22
>
> There is an API endpoint to access these IPs programmatically. Subscribe to the API Changes blog to stay current.
>
> Upcoming IP Addresses
>
> We also own the following block of IP addresses which will be used in
>   the future. This page will be updated once they are in active use.
>
> 2620:112:3000::/44